# Points fixed by the isotropy group of the restricted Poincaré group in Minkowski space

Tags: group-theory, semi-riemannian-geometry, rigid-transformation

What points does the isotropy group $SO(3)$ fix in the Minkowskian case? For instance, in oriented Euclidean 3-space the isotropy group $SO(3)$ of the Euclidean group $E(3)$ fixes the origin. What is the case in Minkowski 4-space with the isotropy group $SO(3)$ for timelike directions?

On request: Consider the action of the Poincaré group on the space of future directed timelike curves. This action is transitive. That means we are considering a single orbit in Minkowski space, not particular orbits with fixed origin of the Lorentz subgroup of the Poincaré group. We are picking as orbit the space of forward cone hyperboloids and the stabilizer that corresponds to each of these hyperboloids in Minkowski space is $SO(3)$(or $SU(2)$ if we consider the doble cover of the Poincare group as usual in QFT).

So it would seem that the whole set of points of the manifold is fixed by the isotropy group in the transitive action of the Poincaré group on Minkowski space, not just the origin of the rotation, which would be the case just for the action of the Lorentz group acting on a point in Minkowski space.
In fact no element of the Poincaré group can act on Minkowski space fixing just a point.

Comment: What exactly is your question? "What is the case..." makes no sense as written.

Comment: The question is: what points does the isotropy group SO(3) fix in the Minkowskian case?.

Comment: Well, it fixes a line in the 4d space.

Comment: Please take some time to think it through and then you might write a proper answer. It is not just a line in 4-space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(L, \langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle)$ be a 4-dimensional Lorentzian space (of signature (3,1)); let $P_+$ denote the orientation-preserving subgroup in the Poincare group $P$ of $(L, \langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle)$:
$$
P_+\cong {\mathbb R}^4\rtimes SO(3,1).
$$
Consider a Lie subgroup $H< P_+$ isomorphic to $SO(3)$. I will use the following neat argument due to Cartan:

Lemma. Let $K$ be a compact group of affine isometries of a Hilbert space ${\mathcal H}$, preserving a nonempty closed convex subset $C\subset {\mathcal H}$. Then $K$ fixes a point in $C$.

Proof. Consider an orbit $Kx\subset C$. Since $K$ is compact, so is the orbit $Kx$. Let $b\in {\mathcal H}$ denote the center  of mass of the orbit $Kx$. Since $C$ is convex and $Kx\subset C$, it follows that $b\in C$. Since the center of mass is unique, it is fixed by $K$. qed.

This lemma has several corollaries. For instance, if $K$ is a compact group of affine transformations of a $n$-dimensional vector space $V$ (or even an infinite dimensional topological vector space as long as it admits 
an inner product), then $K$ acts by isometries of some Euclidean metric on 
$V$. To prove this, consider the action of $K$ on the space of all positive-definite bilinear forms on $V$ (the action is via the pull-back). This space can be seen as a convex subspace in the space of all $n\times n$-symmetric matrices; the latter has an invariant inner product given by $tr(A^TB)$. Hence, by the above lemma, $K$ has a fixed point in the space of positive-definite bilinear products on $V$, hence, preserves some Euclidean metric on $V$. Applying the lemma one more time, to now the action of $K$ on $V$ itself, we conclude that $K$ has a fixed point in $V$.

Corollary. Let $K$ be a compact group of affine transvormations of a Hilbert space ${\mathcal H}$, preserving a nonempty closed convex subset $C\subset {\mathcal H}$. Then $K$ fixes a point in $C$.

I now go back to your question. Since $H\cong SO(3)$ is compact, the group $H$ fixes a point in $L$. I will declare this point to be the origin $o$ in $L$, i.e. $H$ is contained in the stabilizer $P_o$ of  the origin in $P_+$, i.e. in the Lorentz group
$$
P_o\cong SO(3,1). 
$$

Now, $H$ acts on $L$ via linear transformations. The next thing to observe is that $H$ fixes a time-like vector $v\in L$, i.e. a vector such that $\langle v, v \rangle <0$. Indeed, $P_o$ preserves the set
$$
\{x\in L: \langle x, x\rangle\le -1\}.  
$$
This set is not convex but it is the disjoint union of two convex connected components $C_+, C_-$ (future and past directions). Since $SO(3)$ is connected, it preserves both $C_+$ and $C_-$. Since $H$ preserves $C_+$, by applying the Corollary, we conclude that $H$ fixes a vector $v\in C_+$.

Hence, we obtain:

Lemma. 1. Every subgroup $H\cong SO(3)$ in $P_o$ fixes pointwise a time-like line $\ell\subset L$. (This is the line spanned by the vector $v$.)

2. Every subgroup $H\cong SO(3)$ in $P_+$ fixes pointwise an affine time-like line $\ell\subset L$.

As far as I can tell, you are asking "what is the fixed-point set of $H$ in $L$ provided that $H< P_+$ is isomorphic to $SO(3)$?"

[Recall that the fixed-point set of a group $H$ acting on a set $S$ is the subset of $S$ consisting of all $x\in S$ such that $h(x)=x$ for all $h\in H$.]

This question has the answer: The affine line $\ell$ defined above.

Let's prove this claim. First of all, as I explained above, we can choose the origin in the affine space $L$ to be a point $o\in \ell$ (fixed by $H$); then $H$ acts linearly on $L$ with respect to this choice of the origin. (I think, this change of the origin is the source of confusion in your comments.)

It is clear from the definition of $H$ that it fixes all points of $\ell$. It also preserves the Lorentzian orthogonal complement $\ell^\perp$ of the line $\ell$. The bilinear form $B=\langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle$ restricts to a positive definite bilinear form on $\ell^\perp$ and $H$ acts on $\ell^\perp$  as the full group of orientation-preserving orthogonal transformations of this form. Hence, $H$ has no nonzero fixed vectors in $\ell^\perp$. Since the fixed point set of $H$ is a linear subspace of $L$, which intersects $\ell^\perp$ only at the origin, it follows that this fixed point set is 1-dimensional, hence, equals to the line $\ell$. qed

Comment: No, I didn't mean neither the restriction of G to the transformations fixing the origin nor the affine translations group. I meant the Poincaré group as G, and its subgroup $SO(3)$ as isotropy group for timelike curves..

Comment: @bonif: My group $\hat{G}$ is the Poincare group. Revise your question to make it answerable.

Comment: The question asks about the Poincaré group's isotropy subgroup, what is there to revise?

Comment: We seem to have some misunderstanding about what $\hat{G}$ and $G$ means. If the former is the group of isometries of the Minkowsk space(Poincaré group), and the latter is its isotropy subgroup for timelike curves $SO(3)$(I don't know why you make it $O(3,1)$) what is there to revise in the question?

Comment: @bonif: Very simple: State (in the question, not in the comments) what your group $G$ is: Is it the full Poincare group or it is one of its finite index subgroups (there are four groups about which one can ask a question). State (in the question, not in the comments) your definition of the isotropy group $H$ of a light-like line (there are two inequivalent definitions: pointwise fixator and setwise stabilizer). Then ask (in the question, not in the comments) what is the fixed point set of such $H$ in the Minkowski space.

Comment: I've been asking the whole time for timelike curves, not lightlike.

Comment: Perhaps the problem is that I come from a physics context. There the isotropy group or stabilizer is called the "little group", and in any text on field theory you are going to find that the subgroup of the Poincaré group that is its "little group" in the massive particle(timelike) case is $SO(3)$(see for instance "The quantum theory of fields" pg 64-72 by Weinberg). If we cannot even agree on this I think it is better to drop the discussion.

Comment: Hint: You shouldn't have fixated yourself on the stabilizer of just a timelike line from the start.